# Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be integers. Show that there exist integers $k$ and $r$ such that the sum $a_k+a_{k+1}+\cdots+a_{k+r}$ is divisible by $n$

Tags: summation

I really didn't understand how to prove this, not even single step, I know we have to use summation formula but which one? And how can we "assume"?

thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can assume anything you want. If you get a countradiction, then the assumption is disproved.

Comment: When you say you didn't understand how to prove it, does that mean you have a proof available to look at. If so, can you post it up to the point where you have a question?

Comment: @quasi: That is a *very* bad idea. To quote my professor: the outcome of a successful proof by contradiction is a contradiction. But the outcome of a mistake in a proof...is also a contradiction.

Comment: It's for exam point of view, I don't understand why people try to close question down. It appeared in Indian Statistical Institute subjective test in year 2008, if I am appearing in a test I have to write a valid answer in given frame of time.I could assume whatever but that won't help me in exam. I'd appreciate if intelligent folks with due respect can help me rather down voting my questions and trying to close them. I want to learn. @quasi

Comment: @quasi No I don't have any solution available to me if I had I wouldn't ask it on here. And I don't understand why people try to close questions they can't answer rather than just ignoring it. I added it so people could help me.

Comment: @Iti Shree: Why do you assume you should use a summation formula?  Do you have some sort of description of the $\{a_k\}_k$ that you did not post?

Comment: I don't have any other information other than what I posted, I assumed it because I really cannot understand how to "prove" it so I am looking for approached to this type of problems. @JacobManaker

Comment: I disagree with the "close" proposal. The posters assumption that one should use a "formula" identifies a particular misunderstanding.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Consider the $n$ sums $$a_1,a_1+a_2,a_1+a_2+a_3,\dots,a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n$$
modulo $n$. If all of them are different, what can you conclude? If two of them are the same, what can you say about their difference (one sum minus the other)?

Comment: I didn't quite understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: How many possible distinct residues are there modulo $n$?

Comment: He's using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHardy for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

"Formulas" are meant to be used; not to be a substitute for understanding.

Suppose, for example, that $n=6$.

Consider
\begin{align}
a_1 \mathbin{\%} 6 & = \text{?} \\[4pt]
(a_1+a_2) \mathbin{\%} 6 & = \text{?} \\[4pt]
(a_1+a_2+a_3) \mathbin{\%} 6 & = \text{?} \\[4pt]
(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4) \mathbin{\%} 6 & = \text{?} \\[4pt]
(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5) \mathbin{\%} 6 & = \text{?} \\[4pt]
(a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+a_6) \mathbin{\%} 6 & = \text{?}
\end{align}
where $a\mathbin{\%} b$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$.

Each of the six remainders above is one of $0,1,2,3,4,5.$

If $0$ is one of those, then the sum on the left side is divisible by $6$.

If $0$ is not one of those, then the pigeonhole principle applies: You have to fill six spaces each with one of five numbers, so two of them must be equal to each other. Suppose, for example, that the third and fifth ones are equal:
$$
\Big( (a_1+a_2+a_3) \mathbin{\%} 6\Big) = \Big((a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5) \mathbin{\%} 6\Big).
$$
It follows that the difference between them, $a_4+a_5,$ is divisible by $6$.